# show and hide menu with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I would like,when clicking on the menu icon change to an X shape with animation and when clicking on X shape it change to menu icon.

I write this part.I have problem with clicking function. at first when I click on the menu button it change to X shape and show the menu but when I want to close menu my js codes does not work and I don't know why this happening.
I used bootstrap in my codes
I upload my site [here](http://carpediem.ir/asrnovin/payamap/)

html

```
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <a class="bazar" href="">دانلود اپلیکیشن </a>

    <button type="button" style="z-index:401" class="navbar-toggle try-op" > 
      <span style="z-index:401" class="icon-bar top-m"></span> 
      <span style="z-index:401" class="icon-bar mid-m"></span> 
      <span style="z-index:401" class="icon-bar bottom-m"></span> 
    </button>

    <div class="menu"> <!-- <span class="btnClose">×</span> -->
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">صفحه اصلی</a></li>
        <li><a href="question.html">سوالات متداول</a></li>
        <li><a href="job.html">فرصت های شغلی</a></li>
        <li><a href="aboutus.html">درباره ما</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

js

```
$('.try-op').click(function() {
        $('.navbar-toggle').removeClass('try-op');
        $('.navbar-toggle').addClass('texting');
        $('.top-m').addClass('top-animate');
        $('.mid-m').addClass('mid-animate');
        $('.bottom-m').addClass('bottom-animate');
        $('.menu').addClass('opened');
        var height = $( window ).height();
        $('.menu').css('height',height);

});

    $('.texting').click(function() {
        $('.navbar-toggle').removeClass('texting');
        $('.menu').removeClass('opened');
        $('.top-m').removeClass('top-animate');
        $('.mid-m').removeClass('mid-animate');
        $('.bottom-m').removeClass('bottom-animate');
        $('.navbar-toggle').addClass('try-op');

});
```

css

```
.icon-bar{

    transition: 0.6s ease;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(.75, 0, .29, 1.01);

}
.top-animate {
    background: #fff !important;
    top: 13px !important;
   -webkit-transform: rotate(43deg);
    transform: rotate(43deg);
    transform-origin: 7% 100%;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 7% 100%;
}
.mid-animate {
    opacity: 0;
}
.bottom-animate {
    background: #fff !important;
    top: 13px !important;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-221deg);
    transform: rotate(-221deg);
    transform-origin: 45% 18%;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 45% 18%;
     margin-top: 0px !important;
 }
.bazar-green, .bazar {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 80px;
  top: 5px;
  line-height: 43px;
  background: url(image/bazarlogo.png) no-repeat left center;
  padding-left: 80px;
  z-index: 401;
}


.navbar-toggle {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}

.navbar-toggle{
float: right;
padding: 9px 10px;
margin-top: 8px;
margin-right: 15px;
margin-bottom: 8px;
background-color: transparent;
background-image: none;
border: 1px solid transparent;
border-radius: 4px;
}

.navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
 background-color: #fff;
}
.navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
 display: block;
 width: 22px;
 height: 2px;
 border-radius: 1px;
}
.menu {
width: 300px;
position: absolute;
z-index: 400;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
padding: 10px 30px;
text-align: right;
color: #fff;
font-size: 17px;
transition: all 1s;
right: -316px;
}
.btnClose {
color: #fff;
font-size: 30px;
cursor: pointer;
z-index: 500;
}
```

Comment: did you try with $('.navbar-toggle').click(function() { instead of $('.navbar-toggle span').click(function() {

Comment: Can you provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: @JayPatel yes I test it but no answer.I update my js codes

Comment: @Vohuman in fiddle I replace make my code very clear for you . if you want I can give you github repository address. hole of code is there .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are effectively adding 2 click handlers to the same element. When you click on the `span` elements the second handler is executed, and as the `click` event propagates then the first `click` handler is executed.

You should change the logic. Instead of using `addClass`/`removeClass` and having 2 handlers you can use just 1 click handler and toggle the classNames using `toggleClass` method.

```
$('.try-op').click(function() {
    var isOpened = $('.menu').toggleClass('opened').hasClass('opened');
    if ( isOpened ) {
      // the menu is opened 
    } else {
      // ...
    }
});
```

Another option that you have is using the event delegation technique. I see that you are removing the className in your first handler, probably in order to unbind the handler for the next click handling, but event handlers are bound to elements not to their classNames.

```
$(document).on('click', '.navbar-toggle.open', function() {
   $(this).removeClass('open').addClass('close');    
   // ...
});

$(document).on('click', '.navbar-toggle.close', function() {
   $(this).removeClass('close').addClass('open');    
  // ...
});
```

Comment: ok I get what you mean but how can I do it? I start to learn js recently  so I don't have experience in it.

Comment: @mimi Khahesh mikonam :)

Comment: che khob k y irani in hame reputation dare. baes khushhali bud.

Comment: @mimi Ghorbane shoma! Manam khoshhal shodam yek hamshahri-o tuye SO mibinam ke JavaScript minevise.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$('.navbar-toggle').click(function() {`
 instead of `$('.navbar-toggle span').click(function() {`